# How do I get a total value of the array based on the inner content

Tags: php, arrays, count

here is my array

```
[Computers] => Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [product_id] => 78
           [price] => 999.99
           [quantity] => 2
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [product_id] => 70
           [price] => 49.99
           [quantity] => 6
       )

)


[Scanners] => Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [product_id] => 65
           [price] => 99.99
           [quantity] => 7
       )
   [1] => Array
       (
           [product_id] => 70
           [price] => 149.99
           [quantity] => 5
       )
   [2] => Array
       (
           [product_id] => 70
           [price] => 10.99
           [quantity] => 1
       )

)
```

I was looking for a way to total up the values of the outer arrays based on the inner arrays

so for example the `Computers` array has two products and i need to get the totals based on quantity. So for example (999.99 *2) + (49.99 * 6) = 2299.92 for the computer array and so on...

Comment: buddy, we can't do the entire assignment for you. First sorting, now this? :-p

Comment: `I was looking for a way` - and what did you found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which is untested, but I don´t see why it shouldn´t work

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $sum += $value['quantity'] * $value['price'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach which [maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) the products to sub-totals, then sums those sub-total for each of the items in the outer array.

```
$totals = array_map(function($group){
    return array_sum(array_map(function($product) {
        return $product['price'] * $product['quantity'];
    }, $group));
}, $array);

var_dump($totals, array_sum($totals));
```

Comment: I think even better would be to use array_reduce

Comment: @Karolis - Yes indeed there are many ways to get this job done that would be a perfectly acceptable way. Better, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$sum=0;
foreach ($computers as $pc) {
   $sum += ($pc["price"] * $pc["quantity"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $total = 0;
  for( $i = 0; $i < count( Computers ); $i++ ){
       $total += ( Computers[$i]['price'] * Computers[$i]['quantity'] );
  }
```